# Double Integrals involving Bessel Function of zeroth order

Tags: integration

I need some help solving the integrals below,

$$ 
I_1 = \int_0^a \int_{0}^{R} k\left( {\partial \over \partial z} {\mathrm e^{-\mathrm i z \sqrt{a^2 - k^2}} \over \sqrt{a^2 - k^2} } \right)  \cos(a r) J_0(kr) \mathrm d r \,\mathrm d k 
$$

$$ 
I_2 = \int_a^{\infty} \int_{0}^{R} k \, \left( {\partial \over \partial z} {\mathrm e^{-\mathrm i z \sqrt{k^2 - a^2}} \over \sqrt{k^2 - a^2} } \right)  \cos\left(a r\right) J_0(kr) \mathrm d r \,\mathrm d k
$$

, where $J_0$ is the Bessel function of zeroth order, z is real, and a is real and positive. $\mathrm i$ denotes the imaginary unit.

Many thanks!

**Edit: Second Integral had a Copy&Paste error**

$$ 
I_2 = \int_a^{\infty} \int_{0}^{R} k \, \left( {\partial \over \partial z} {\mathrm e^{-z \sqrt{k^2 - a^2}} \over \sqrt{k^2 - a^2} } \right)  \cos\left(a r\right) J_0(kr) \mathrm d r \,\mathrm d k
$$

Comment: I've seen a lot of integrals over wavenumbers in physics problems, and I've never seen these kinds of wave propagation problems have closed form answers.

Comment: The term in parentheses can be simplified to equal $-ie^{-iz\sqrt{k^2 - a^2}}$ in $I_2$, $-ie^{-iz\sqrt{a^2 - k^2}}$ in $I_1$

Comment: Yes, I was not sure, if it would be beneficial to do the integrations first and then evaluate the derivative w.r.t $z$